# Typo mistake in Rudin Book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have some confusion in Rudin book

My confusion is given below marked in red colour

[image]

Here  both $f$ and $g$ don't look like characteristics function since charcteristic function

look like $$f_{r}(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x\in V_r \\ 0, & x\notin V_r. \end{cases} $$

$$g_{s}(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x\in \bar{V_s} \\ 0, & x\notin \bar{V_s}. \end{cases} $$

**My confusion**: why  $f$ is lower semicontinious  and $g$ is upper semicontinious?

**My attempt** : $$f_{r}(x)=\begin{cases}r, & x\in V_r \\ 0, & x\notin V_r. \end{cases} $$

$$\implies f^{-1}(-\infty , r)=\{ x : f(x) < r\}= \begin{cases}X &\text{if r >1} \\ X \setminus V_r &\text{ if 0 <r} \le 1, \\ \emptyset,& \text{r <0}. \end{cases} $$

Here  $V_r$  is open $\implies X \setminus V_r$ is closed

so  by the theorem  characteristics function  of closed  set are upper semi-continious

we conclude that $f$ is upper- semicontnious

similarly for $g(x)$

$$\implies g^{-1}(-\infty , s)=\{ x : g(x) < s\}= \begin{cases}X &\text{if s >1} \\ X \setminus \bar{V_s} &\text{ if 0 <s} \le 1, \\ \emptyset,& \text{ s<0}. \end{cases} $$

Here  $\bar{V_s}$  is closed   $\implies X \setminus \bar{V_s}$ is open

so  by the theorem  characteristics function  of open  set are lower semi-continious

we conclude that $g$ is lower- semicontnious

Edits : I think  rudin made typo mistake  and my   attempt  is almost correct

Comment: Your argument is fine.  But redundant.  The function $f_r$ is a positive constant $r$ times a characteristic function of an open set.

Comment: @GEdgar i think rudin made typomistake in his book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was wrong**

$\implies f^{-1}(-\infty , r]$ is closed   mean $f$ is lower semicontinious

$\implies g^{-1}(-\infty , s)$ is  open mean $g$ is  upper semicontnious